# The values in a const list literal must be constants, I am getting this error while adding an Image to Column Widget in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Why am I unable to add an Image here? I am getting this error while adding an Image to Column Widget in Flutter. When I am removing the `new` keyword, I am getting another error. Please check into this issue .  I have made a folder named assets>images>girl-icon.jpg . Also, I have enabled assets from pubspec.yaml file.

```html
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        title: 'My First Flutter App',
        theme: ThemeData(
          scaffoldBackgroundColor: Colors.white,
        ),
        home: const WelcomeScreen());
  }
}

class WelcomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const WelcomeScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('First Page'),
        backgroundColor: Colors.amber,
      ),
      body:Center(

      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: const <Widget> [

          Text("Login",
              style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 30,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              )),
          new Image.asset("assets/images/girl-icon.jpg"),
        ],
        ),
        heightFactor: 30,

      ),
      );
    }}
```

[See screenshot of the problem here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UkzmN.png)

Comment: try to remove new keyword from Image

Comment: I am getting another error when I am doing so. I am getting this error `The constructor being called isn't a const constructor.`

Comment: remove const in ` children: const <Widget> [all you widgets]`

Comment: remove const from  `const <Widget>`

Comment: It's working, thanks! @RavindraS.Patil

Answer (score 2):

`const` requires a hard coded `constant` value and you have called **MyApp** as constant while it's `dynamically` being build that is why it's throwing an error. Remove `const` before **MyApp** to solve this issue :

```
void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

and also from here :

```
children: <Widget> [

          Text("Login",
              style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 30,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              )),
          new Image.asset("assets/images/girl-icon.jpg"),
        ]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        title: 'My First Flutter App',
        theme: ThemeData(
          scaffoldBackgroundColor: Colors.white,
        ),
        home: const WelcomeScreen());
  }
}

class WelcomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const WelcomeScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('First Page'),
        backgroundColor: Colors.amber,
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Text("Login",
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 30,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                )),
            Image.asset("assets/images/girl-icon.jpg"),
          ],
        ),
        heightFactor: 30,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

my way is just to remove the

```
const <Widget>
```

Comment: Thanks, it is working !!

Comment: where is my code ;)

Comment: what are you trying to say?